# How do i get values of id’s And also how do i merge multiple objects into single array into javascript

Tags: javascript

[please click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJp1m.png)
How do i get values of id’s And also how do i merge multiple objects into single array

Also for more reference i have an object here and i want values of id's from it

```
var myObj = {

     "cars": [
        {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Ford",
           "models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]
        },
        {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "BMW",
           "models": ["320", "X3", "X5"]
        },
        {
           "id": 3,
           "name": "Fiat",
           "models": ["500", "Panda"]
        }
    ]
}
```

[please click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJp1m.png)
And how do i print id's in the browser like

id - 1
name - ford

id - 2
name - BMW

.......

like so

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: var myObj = {

         "cars": [
            {
               "id": 1,
               "name": "Ford",
               "models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]
            },
            {
               "id": 2,
               "name": "BMW",
               "models": ["320", "X3", "X5"]
            },
            {
               "id": 3,
               "name": "Fiat",
               "models": ["500", "Panda"]
            }
    ]
      }

I have an object and and i want value of id's from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lodash:

```
_.map(myObj.cars, x => x.id)
```

with es6:

```
myObj.cars.map(x => x.id)
```

Comment: And how do i print id's in the page like
id - 1
name - ford

id - 2
name - BMW 

.......

like so

Comment: myObj.cars.map(x => ({id: x.id, name: x.name}));

This will give you an array of objects: {id: 1, name: 'Ford'}, but you already have that in the original object array

Comment: `myObj.cars.forEach(car => console.log('id - ' + car.id + ' name - ' + car.name))`

Comment: I think it should be the accepted answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(myObj.cars[0].id); // output: 1
console.log(myObj.cars[1].id); // output: 2
console.log(myObj.cars[2].id); // output: 3
```

[Learn Javascript's Object here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp).

[Learn JSON here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

Comment: how do i merge multiple objects into single array

Comment: @aman you can find a list of array methods [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp).